# Как написать свой автоустановщик для NodeJS проекта на сервер?

Tags: linux, node.js

Все свои проекты на nodejs мне приходится в ручную каждый раз на сервере устанавливать ОС, nodejs, pm2, mysql, настройка nginx конфиг файла. Этот процесс весьма утомительный. А если вдруг сервер упадет или ещё что, то нужно коннектиться и через pm2 перезапускать все процессы. На чем и как можно написать какой нибудь свой шаблонный установщик?

Comment: Используйте Docker